# Inserting row in SAP Hana 2.0 with Hibernate

Tags: scala, hibernate, hana

I'm trying to insert a row in a SAP Hana 2.0 database using Hibernate in Scala code. The table has an identity column.

This is the table:

```
CREATE column TABLE banks (
  sk tinyint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  code varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  name varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  notes text,
  version smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (sk)
);
```

This is the Hibernate annotated class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "banks")
class BankHib {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var sk: Int = _

    var code: String = _
    var name: String = _
    var notes: String = _
    var version: Int = _
}
```

This is the insert code:

```
    session.beginTransaction
    val b = new BankHib
    b.code = "B3"
    b.name = "xxxxx"
    b.version = 1
    b.notes = "aaa"
    session.save(b)
    session.getTransaction.commit
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

> Hibernate: insert into banks (code, name, notes, version) values (?,
>   ?, ?, ?)
>
> [warn] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: -11262,
>   SQLState: 0A000 [error] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - Method
>   prepareStatement( String, int ) of Statement is not supported. [error]
>   application -

How to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to create a sequence number as identity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "banks")
class BankHib {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "bank_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="bank_generator", sequenceName="bankSeq", allocationSize=1)    
    var sk: Int = _

    var code: String = _
    var name: String = _
    var version: Int = _
}
```

And execute the following SQL statement:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE bankSeq start with 1 increment by 1 minvalue 1
```